# How to auto-select next row after deleting current row by core data context?

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-data, nstableview

I am using `Core Data` to manage objects and using a `NSTableView` to display those objects. The table columns are binded to objects' properties through a `NSArrayController`.

When users click the delete button, all selected objects in the `NSTableView` will be deleted. Then only remained objects are left in the `NSTableView`.

This works smoothly. But after deleting selected rows, `NSTableView` does not select a row automatically. As a result, users have to type once arrow key or use mouse to select a new row.

So my question is: how could I make `NSTableView` select the next or previous row after selected rows are deleted?

Of course, I could just select a left row programmatically after deleting. But I am wondering whether there is a more elegant way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Whether or not you're using bindings (your table columns are bound to an NSArrayController) makes all the difference in the answer. Are you or aren't you? :-) Without bindings, it's relatively easy; with, it's considerably more cumbersome.

Comment: Yes, I am using bindings to a NSArrayController to render table columns. The rows are deleted just because I delete the selected rows from Core Data. Refine the question to clarify this.